# How can we prove or disprove this conjecture on a family of ellipsoids?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

**Conjecture:** For every positive definite matrix $A_{n\times n} \succ 0$, whose main diagonal is all ones, i.e. $\text{diag}(A)=\vec{1}$, there exists an orthant (quadrant) $Q \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, such that for all solutions ${\bf{x}} \in Q \setminus (-1,1)^n$ of the following equation:
\begin{equation}
{\bf{x}}^TA{\bf{x}}=n^2,
\end{equation}
we have ${\bf{x}}^T{\bf{x}} \leq n^2$. In other words, the points on the ellipsoid (${\bf{x}}^TA{\bf{x}}=n^2$) are inside a closed $n$-ball with radius $n$, for every ${\bf{x}} \in Q$ which also satisfy $|{\bf{x}}_i|\geq 1$ for each coordinate.

**Special case:** To clarify more, let's look at the case when $n=2$. Here, our particular family of ellipsoids is the solution of
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
x & y \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a \\
a & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{bmatrix}=4, \quad {\text{for}} \; a\in (-1,+1).
\end{equation}
For example, let $a=0.4$, and we have the following diagram:

$\qquad\quad$[image: Ellipsoid in two dim]

In this case, for quadrants I and III, all points on the ellipsoid are inside the ball, hence the regions with $|x|\geq 1$ and $|y|\geq 1$ in these quadrants (the yellow lines) are also inside the ball.

I have tested the above conjecture for different dimensions and numerous values and it turned out to be valid for all of them, but how can we prove it?
Thanks!

Comment: How did it come up, what made you believe it to do the testing? Was there a different problem that made suggested this one?

Comment: I was trying to prove the conjecture 4 of [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123608002474) and the above conjecture came up.